# Host MVC 2 app in subfolder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I had to host an MVC 2 project on a godaddy server lets say `www.example.com`, it works fine at top level but I also need to host another MVC 2 project in subfolder lets say `www.example.com/list` , I did that but its not working well....can anyone suggest how I can configure the web config file of subfolder MVC hosted application?

Thanks

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive when saying `but its not working well`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new **virtual directory** in the root and point the domain to it. Like:

```
-Root << www.example.com points here
 /List  << add a virtual dir, point it to a folder,
           make sure example.com/list points here.
```

That should be it. Asp.net MVC is supported by Godaddy AFAIK. Make you set things like .NET Framework version.